# MultiScaleImage in Windows Phone 8 app with local source

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, deepzoom, multiscaleimage

I'm trying to use MultiScaleImage in a WP8 app with local source. I've composed the image structure using Deep Zoom Composer and added the files to the app project.

```
<MultiScaleImage x:Name="ImageMap" Source="Map/dzc_output.xml" />
```

The above doesn't work, no errors, just doesn't display anything. I also tried setting the source from code, but no success.

```
ImageMap.Source = new DeepZoomImageTileSource()
{
    UriSource = new Uri("file:///Map/dzc_output.xml")
};
```

I did not try with remote source - for purposes of this application I need strictly local source.
Sadly, the documentation is very poor on explaining how this (or if) can be done in Windows Phone. Has anyone attempted this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MultiScaleImage doesn't support local images as tile source. There was proposal to support local storage, but it was not accepted.

https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-dev-platform/suggestions/1946653-deep-zoom-pan-multiscale-image

Answer (score 0):

Please try these path formats:

[image: windows phone file path format]

`ms-appx://` is good.

if `ms-appx://` doesn't work, you can try `Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path` or `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` to get your installation path. Then append your file path, it works in code-behind.

Comment: Where do you put your file? Assets or IsolationStorage? @TomislavMarkovski

Comment: I tried both, did not work. When you say "it works in code-behind", do you mean that it worked for you to set the source of the MultiscaleImage to a file located in local storage in a Windows Phone 8 app? Would you mind providing some source code?